# Drupal (7.x) and Frei Chat Overlay and chat room conflict

Tags: drupal-7

Recently I have faced a weird problem with Frei chat and drupal overlay interface.
The chat room button/option floating in the middle and make Overlay section unusable specially module install and uninstalling.

So I have searched the internet for the solution but got no answer .

Answer (score 0):

So I have decided to hide the chat room button if overlay is opened. 
Just put the css in the freichat/client/themes/basic/styles.css file -

**Bellow is the css:-**

```
 html.overlay-open .frei_chatroom
{
    display:none !important;    
}
```

If any one know better solution please reply.